# Map causing Seg Fault. How to increase memory?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, dictionary, segmentation-fault

I have a simple question.  I have a few files, one file is around ~20000 lines.
It has 5 fields, have some other adt (vectors and lists), but those do not cause a segfault.
The map itself will store a key value, equivalent to about 1 per line.
When I added a map to my code, I would instantly get a segfault, I copied 5000 of 20000 lines, and receive a segfault, then 1000, and it worked.

In java there is a way to increase the amount of virtually allocated memory, is there a way to do so in c++?  I have even deleted elements as they are no longer used, and I can get around 2000 lines, but not more.

Here is gdb:

```
(gdb) exec-file readin
(gdb) run
Starting program: /x/x/x/readin readin

Program exited normally.
```

valgrind:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==7948==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7948==   total heap usage: 20,206 allocs, 20,206 frees, 2,661,509 bytes allocated
==7948== 
==7948== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

code:

```
 ....
 Flow flw = endQueue.top();
  stringstream str1;
  stringstream str2;
  if (flw.getSrc() < flw.getDest()){
    str1 << flw.getSrc();
    str2 << flw.getDest();
    flw_src_dest = str1.str() + "-" + str2.str();
  } else {
    str1 << flw.getSrc();
    str2 << flw.getDest();
    flw_src_dest = str2.str() + "-" + str1.str();
  }    
while (int_start > flw.getEnd()){
  if(flw.getFlow() == 1){
    ava_bw[flw_src_dest] += 5.5;
  } else {
    ava_bw[flw_src_dest] += 2.5;
  }
  endQueue.pop();
}
```

Comment: Post your code. It's broken somewhere...

Comment: Are you sure the segmentation fault is due to memory allocation problems?  Have you run the code in GDB?  It seems unlikely that a map would fail after 1,000 entries.

Comment: If you are doing this in a modern virtual memory environment, the problem is the code handling the map, not the lack of memory.  In Linux a resource error would appear for memory limitations, not a SEGFAULT.

Comment: I havent used a debugged, so let me try that, and I will get back to you all.

Comment: Is it a `std::map` or did you roll your own map class? You are unlikely seeing the segmentation fault due to any of the standard C++ containers. We need to see some code...

Comment: Code is posted that uses map, as well as the debug output, I have never used valgrind, so its output is lost on me.

Comment: @Jim, is `flw_src_dest` guaranteed to be in the map? I.e. the same as `src_dest` that you set to `INIT` if it does not exist? Also, is `(int_start > flw.getEnd())` what you mean? I'm not sure how your program side-effects change these values...

Comment: So there are 2 types of things, I have a queue of Flows, a class I wrote myself, just contains a bunch of ints, I store this in the endQueue. endQueue.top() is Flow flw.  So this is a FLOW that has already started, but needs to end in chronical order, so it is thrown in a priorouty queue.  int_start is the current start time, so if that is greater than glw.getEnd(), the first end time in the priority queue, then it will make sure to grab it before it adds the start time.  INIT is a const set to 200.0.

Comment: @Jim, when you do `endQueue.pop()` how does `flw` become the new `endQueue.top()`?

Comment: @Jim let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1196/discussion-between-dave-rager-and-jim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful erasing elements from a container while you are iterating over the container.

```
for (pos = ava_bw.begin(); pos != ava_bw.end(); ++pos) {
    if (pos->second == INIT){
      ava_bw.erase(pos);
    }
  }
```

I believe this will have `pos` pointing to the next value but then `++pos` will advance it yet again. If `erase(pos)` resulted in `pos` pointing at `ava_bw.end()`, the `++pos` will fail.

I know if you tried this with a vector, `pos` will be invalidated.

### Edit

In the while loop you do

```
while (int_start > flw.getEnd()){
   if(flw.getFlow() == 1){
      ava_bw[flw_src_dest] += 5.5;
   } else {
      ava_bw[flw_src_dest] += 2.5;
   }
   endQueue.pop();
}
```

You need to do `flw = endQueue.top()` again.

Comment: It does what it suppose to do though?  I mean I commented this out and I will still get a seg-fault.

Comment: Sorry for all the edits. `erase()` has different side effects depending on the container on which it invoked.

Answer (score 6):

A segmentation fault doesn't necessarily indicate that you're out of memory. In fact, with C++, it's *highly unlikely*: you would usually get a `bad_alloc` or somesuch in this case (unless you're dumping everything in objects with automatic storage duration?!).

More likely, you have a memory corruption bug in your code, that *just so happens* to only be noticeable when you have more than a certain number of objects.

**At any rate, the solution to memory faults is not to blindly throw more memory at the program.**

Run your code through valgrind and through a debugger, and see what the real problem is.

Comment: I ran through the debugger, but I didnt find any problems.

Comment: @Jim: _valgrind_ would have revealed this problem. Please **do** install it for continued future use as part of your _normal development environment_, and don't just ignore my suggestion because your immediate bug has been solved.

Comment: Will do, the server I run most of my code off of does not have it.  However I found a version for my pc to run it.

Comment: @Jim: You should get _valgrind_ into your development environment as a matter of course. It's available for Linux. What OS do you develop on?

Comment: mac os.  I have to use ports.  I am working on getting that working.

Comment: "Mac OS" (you mean OSX?) doesn't exist for PCs. The second result for my Google search for `valgrind mac` sends me to [the valgrind website page on platforms](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html), which in turn suggests that Mac OSX is supported... at least partially.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in C\C++ max amount of available heap isn't fixed at start of the program -- you can always allocate some more memory, either via direct usage of `new/malloc` or by using STL containers, such as `stl::list`, which can do it by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is memory, as C++ gets as much memory as it asks for, even hogging all available memory on your PC. Look if you `delete` something you access later on.

Comment: I am not using delete.  I am using erase from std::map.